# Проблема с кодировкой mysqli

Tags: кодировка, mysqli

Кодировка страницы UTF-8.
Кодировка таблицы utf8_general_ci.
ОС сервера ubuntu-14.04-x86_64-minimal.

В таблицу записываются комментарии в кириллице, в phpmyadmin в таблице они записываются в таком виде: Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð

Но на сайте отображаются комментарии нормально, подскажите что надо сделать что бы текст корректно отображался в таблице?

Пробовал добавить mysqli_set_charset ($c, "utf8");
В таблице текст стал отображаться нормально, но на сайте при выборке: ??? ?? ????

Comment: Проверьте настройки  phpmyadmin

Comment: Что именно надо поправить?

Comment: Если сайт и база дружат, а phpmyadmin - нет, то, скорее всего, именно в phpmyadmin "другие" настройки кодировки отображения

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос исчерпан. Установил ещё на странице отображения `mysqli_set_charset ($db, "utf8");`